# Android - Widget with configuration activity, how to keep initialised data on onUpdate

Tags: java, android, configuration, widget, provider

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

I read this and other tutorials to make Widget with user configuration.

I understood that ConfigurationActivity would initialise the widget, but the widget will be updated with "onUpdate" method in provider class.

Then my question is, how do I make the widget keep the initialised data when onUpdate is called?

For example, this is what I have in configurationActivity, that takes String input from user and set it in textView

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_haruhi);

//Get String input.
            String test = String.valueOf(name.getText());
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sinceWhen, test);

//But after 30 min it calls default update??

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, remoteViews);
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
```

And this is what I have in Widget provider

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_haruhi);
        long days=getDays(2011,5,15);
//This field needs to be updated periodically
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.daysText, days+context.getString(R.string.days)); 

// But this field needs to stay the same as initialised configuration
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.daysText, ????); 


        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HaruhiWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
```

One field in widget needs to be updated periodically
but the other one needs to show the String as input by user.
but by the time onUpdate is called, this widget gets reset and the initialise value would be lost.

How do I approach this problem? Should I save all initialised data in SharedPreference and load all the data everytime update signal is received?

Comment: I am in the same situation right now and I think we have to save the data in shared preferences